# Use only a Fragment Shader in libGDX?

Tags: opengl, shader, libgdx

I am porting my project from pure LWJGL to libGDX, and I'd like to know if there is a way to create a program only with the Fragment Shader?

What I'd like to do is to change the color of my texture where it is gray to a color I receive as a parameter. The shader worked perfectly before, but now, it seems that I need to add a Vertex Shader - what does not make any sense to me. So I wrote this:

```
void main() {
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

That, according to the internet, is the simplest possible VS: it does nothing, and it really shouldn't. But it doesn't work: nothing is displayed, and no compilation errors or warnings are thrown. I tried to replace my Fragment Shader with a simpler one, but the results were even stranger:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

This should only paint everything in red. But when I run, the program crashes, no error is thrown, no Exception, very odd behavior. I know that libGDX adds tilting, but I don't think it would work either, because I need to replace only the gray-scale colors, and depending on the intensity, I need to correctly modulate the correct color (that is varying). Another shader I am using (Fragment only, again) is to set the entire scene to gray-scale (when on the pause menu). It won't work either.

Comment: What Libgdx APIs are you using?  Are you just using the raw OpenGL wrappers?  Or are you using higher-level APIs like `SpriteBatch` and `ShaderProgram`?  Are you checking that your shader compiled correctly and checking its log output?

Comment: did you use presision

Comment: I am using high level classes, including SpriteBatch and ShaderProgram. I am also using Texture, but not Sprite nor Scene2D. When I create the shaders, it gives no errors and no warnings through the getLog() method. And I don't know what presision means (and neither precision, if that is what you meant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to shaders in modern OpenGL you always have to supply at least a vertex and a fragment shader. OpenGL-2 gave you some leeway, at the drawback, that you then still have to struggle with the arcane fixed function state machine.

> That, according to the internet, is the simplest possible VS: it does nothing, and it really shouldn't.

What makes you think it does "nothing". Of course it does something: It translates incoming, raw numbers into something sensible, namely vertices in clip space.

Comment: What I meant was that it should have the same behavior as having no shaders at all; I do not want to change the position of the vertexes, so that was why I had no VS before...

Comment: @LuanNico: A vertex shader does not "change" the position of the vertices. It turns raw numbers, that could mean anything into actual vertex data the GPU can work with. Without having something running on the vertex transformation stage there's nothing that a GPU could actually turn into pixels. So you absolutely need a vertex shader. `ftransform();` mimics the fixed function pipeline behavior. If you can live with it, use it. But it pins you down on using the fixed pipeline state variables, which are very cumbersome to work with.

Comment: OK, I think I understood it: if no shaders were provided, there would still be a 'shader', that would just call fransform() to do the default stuff. My problem should be in the other shader, then...